# Why does SQL UNION perform so poorly unless core with clause is duplicated?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a main with clause (DATA1) that I'm using and if I try to union two queries using the with clause, it takes minutes to run. However, both queries run separately within one second.  The following sample took 2.5 minutes to run:

```
WITH 
DATA1 AS 
(
  T1.COL1 AS T_1
, T2.COL3 AS T_3
, T2.COL4 AS T_4
, T3.COL2 AS T_2
FROM 
    TABLE1 T1
JOIN 
    TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1
JOIN 
    TABLE3 T3 ON T1.COL1 = T3.COL1
)
SELECT
    DATA1.*
FROM
    DATA1
WHERE 
    T_1 = 16573
AND 
    T_4 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    DATA1.*
FROM
    DATA1
WHERE
    T_1 = 23424
AND 
    T_4 IS NOT NULL
```

The sample below took 1 second to run after duplicating the main with clause into DATA2.  I don't understand why it's working this way or how to avoid having to do it this way?  I also tried aliasing DATA1 as DATA2 in the second query, but it still ran slow.

```
WITH 
DATA1 AS 
(
  T1.COL1 AS T_1
, T2.COL3 AS T_3
, T2.COL4 AS T_4
, T3.COL2 AS T_2
FROM 
     TABLE1 T1
JOIN 
    TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1
JOIN 
    TABLE3 T3 ON T1.COL1 = T3.COL1
),
DATA2 AS 
(
  T1.COL1 AS T_1
, T2.COL3 AS T_3
, T2.COL4 AS T_4
, T3.COL2 AS T_2
FROM 
    TABLE1 T1
JOIN 
    TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1
JOIN 
    TABLE3 T3 ON T1.COL1 = T3.COL1
)
SELECT
    DATA1.*
FROM
    DATA1
WHERE 
    T_1 = 16573
AND 
    T_4 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    DATA2.*
FROM
    DATA2
WHERE
    T_1 = 23424
AND 
    T_4 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You probably need to look at the execution plans to see what it's doing. Is there a reason you aren't using a single query with `T_1 = 16573 OR T_1 = 23424` or `T_1 IN(16573, 23424)`? How does it perform if you do?

Comment: @Mike . . . If I had to guess, it is because Oracle decides to materialize the CTE when it is referred to twice, but it does not when referred to once.

Comment: Gordon, I think this is it, thank you. I'm going to do some refactoring  and see if I can get the improvement that way.